# Outlook PST file / error / <We didn't find anything to show here>

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

Just used the export feature of MS Outlook 2016 to backup my emails.

1. Created a PST file and dragged items into the data file.
2. The file has a nice size (+120 MB).
3. I closed down MS Outlook and re-started it and opened the archive.

It indicates that I have data (e.g. ### items unread), but it won't display any message.

Older archives I made in a similar way appear to behave as I expected.

What might be the problem?

**Portion of folder tree indicating I opened archive named 'E-mail 2017'**

[image]

**Banner indicating no messages to show me**
[image: Banner indicating no messages to show me]

Comment: Maybe try to open the .pst with thunderbird or some other email client. That'll at least tell you if the .PST is working.

Comment: Good idea.  Will check...  Didn't know that T-bird accepts PST.

Comment: It might not, actually. You might have to convert the .PST into something Tbirdie likes better. I had to do that once. Wasn't fun. Like I said, at least you'll know if it's your .PST or just Outlook being.. Outlook.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: Click on `View`, then click on `Change View`, then change the state from `Hide Messages Marked for Deletion` to `Preview`.

Comment: brilliant - you saved me from email disaster- working on windows 10 and office 365 perfectly

Answer (score 2):

MNos' post worked for me.

I noticed that the messages were still 'marked for deletion', so in each item's right-click menu, there was 'undelete' but 'delete' was greyed out.

This link describes a macro to change the message and folder type, as it relates to the type (IPF.Imap vs IPF.Note). I have just tried it and it appears to work brilliantly.

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/change-outlook-folder-type-export/

Answer (score 0):

According to the last image, it seems that you selected the root folder. Please locate to "Inbox" to check the result.

Comment: Thanks, but I did do that already.